# sql update set ? = ? where ? = ? (python, sqlite3)

Tags: python, sqlite

Python, slite3

```
c.execute("UPDATE accounts SET ? = ? WHERE num=?", (db['choise'], db['data'], db['num']))
```

so i don't know what is wrong with it

db is shelve database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column (and table) names *cannot be parameterized*. Use string formatting for it and query parameterization for the rest of variables:

```
c.execute("UPDATE accounts SET {column} = ? WHERE num = ?".format(column=db['choise']), (db['data'], db['num']))
```

That said, make sure you properly validate/sanitize/escape the `db['choise']` value or really trust the source of it (though don't trust anyone when it comes to database interactions).

Answer (score 1):

Column names cannot be given as arguments. You can try

```
c.execute("UPDATE accounts SET "+str(db['choise'])+" = ? WHERE num=?", (db['data'], db['num']))
```